# Find text in files and then rename the files, in Batch

Tags: windows, batch, rename, findstr

i'm having some problems creating a script that find a specific text in each file inside a folder, get the content after that text and set it as a name for the file, all that inside a loop, to perform the same on multiple files.

example, i have a folder with file1, file2, file3

```
content in file1: sw_part = "ABC-DEF.GHJ";
content in file2: sw_part = "ABC-123.XYZ";
content in file3: sw_part = "ABCDE-FGHJ.KLMN";
```

The result should be:

```
file1 renamed to ABC-DEF.GHJ
file2 renamed to ABC-123.XYZ
file3 renamed to ABCDE-FGHJ.KLMN
```

What i made is this:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr /I "sw_part" file1') do set "swpart=%%a"  
echo sw part is: %swpart%   
copy file1 "%swpart%"
```

This works fine, but it works only for a given file (I can't make it work with a loop) and also it rename the file with **`;`** at the end.
Any help?

It need to be done in BATCH. PowerShell is also ok.

Thanks

Comment: This is much, much, much easier in powershell than batch, but I don't really understand the question too well to provide an answer. Also, can there be more content in that file? can it have multiple swpart strings? and is it swpart or sw_part?

Comment: yes it can have more content, but only one sw_part and what really matter for rename the file.

Comment: are there spaces too? sw_part = filename, or is it sw_part=filename?

Comment: It has spaces before and after the = char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will do what you want.

```
cd C:\temp\swpart

$files = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

select-string -Path "*.*" -Pattern "sw_part" | ForEach-Object {
   
    $old_filename = $_.Filename

    $new_filename = $_.line -replace "^.*sw_part = ""","" -replace """.*$",""


    # put everything in array, so the files get closed and can be renamed later.
    $null = $files.Add(@{"old"=$old_filename;"new"=$new_filename})

}

$files |ForEach-Object{
    $old_filename = $_.old
    $new_filename = $_.new

    rename-item $old_filename $new_filename -Force
}
```

Make sure you alter the first row to change to the path of where the files are.

If for some reason not all files are renamed, run the script again. Then the file was still in use.

Comment: looks like i talked too fast! it works only for the first file :(

Comment: i fixed it by moving the last live (rename-item $old_filename $new_filename -Force), inside $files |ForEach-Object{

}

Comment: Ah, right! What was I thinking. Fixed with an edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

- With PowerShell, you can also do this using just two lines:

```bat
ls 'F:\2020-SU\Q1605996\*.txt'|%{$new=(cat $_.FullName).split('\"*\"')[-2];ren $_.FullName -new $new -force}
```

- Without  using aliases:

```bat
Get-ChildItem 'F:\2020-SU\Q1605996\*.txt' | ForEach {
      $new=(Get-Content $_.FullName).split('\"*\"')[-2]
      Rename-Item $_.FullName -new $new -force
     }
```

---

---

- You can also to do this with cmd in just one line:

In command line:

```bat
for /f tokens^=1-3delims^=^:^"^" %a in ('findstr . *.txt')do @ren "%~fa" "%~c"
```

In bat/cmd file:

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder"
for /f tokens^=1-3delims^=:^"^" %%a in ('findstr . *.txt')do @ren "%%~fa" "%%~c"
```

---

`Findstr` command and output

```bat
>F:\Q1605996>findstr . *.txt
file1.txt:sw_part = "ABC-DEF.GHJ";
file2.txt:sw_part = "ABC-123.XYZ";
file3.txt:sw_part = "ABCDE-FGHJ.KLMN";
file4.txt:sw_part = "ABCDE-FGHJ.KXMN";more test/strings
file5.txt:this is a test; sw_part = "fea.geow.eaf.gae"; this is another test;
```

`For` loop command mechanic

```bat
set yours delimiters : + " + "   ==>>    delims^=:^"^" 
set yours tokens "1" - "3"             ==>>    tokens^=1-3
              :        =                  ;
     token = 1:token =2=         token = 3;
     file1.txt:sw_part = "ABC-DEF.GHJ"    ;
     file2.txt:sw_part = "ABC-123.XYZ"    ;
     file3.txt:sw_part = "ABCDE-FGHJ.KLMN";
     file4.txt:sw_part = "ABCDE-FGHJ.KXMN";more test/strings
    |         |          |               |
ren    "%f~a"                  "%~c"
ren "F:\Q1605996\file1.txt"  "ABC-DEF.GHJ"
ren "F:\Q1605996\file2.txt"  "ABC-123.XYZ"
ren "F:\Q1605996\file3.txt"  "ABCDE-FGHJ.KLMN"
ren "F:\Q1605996\file4.txt"  "ABCDE-FGHJ.KXMN"


rem :: The same in file5.txt 
     file5.txt:this is a test;sw_part = "fea.geow.eaf.gae"; this is another test;
    |         |                         |                |
ren    "%f~a"                                 "%~c"
ren "F:\Q1605996\file5.txt"             "fea.geow.eaf.gae"
```

---

**Additional resources PowerShell:**

- [`Split()`](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)
- [`Replace()`](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)
- [`Substring()`](https://ss64.com/ps/substring.html)
- [`Rename-Item` | `ren`](https://ss64.com/ps/rename-item.html)
- [`ForEach-Object` | `%` | `?`](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)
- [`Get-Content` | `type` | `cat`](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)
- [`Get-ChildItem` | `ls` | `dir`](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)

**Additional resources cmd/batch:**

- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [`Ren /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)
- [`Move /Y`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)
- [`Findstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Comment: I don't think this will work because the files don't just contain the lines sw_part = filename, but also stuff before and after it.

Comment: I asked, file1 can be: `this is a test; sw_part = "fea.geow.eaf.gae"; this is another test;` and I might be wrong, but quickly glancing at your example, I'd say this would not work, especially if the file has enters. When I wrote my script, the enters is what made it break.

Comment: @LPChip Humm, this change something...